# Not getting mail updates from cloud pub/sub topic watch

Tags: cloud, gmail-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created topic on cloud pub/sub,then created subscription to it(Push into an endpoint url).Set watch on inbox mails of that topic.Watch set successfully still i am not getting any updates of new mails.How to get notify about mails?

Comment: Did you grant Gmail access to the Pubsub Topic via SetIam Policy on Pubsub Topic?

Comment: Furhan Shabir, Yes!!! Thanks i got the error!!!

Comment: So do you still have this problem, or is it solved?